# How to turn the grey background white in a phone camera picture of a book?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cs6, background-removal

Here is a picture (of many) that I took from a book with my phone camera.[image]

The problem is that the background is too grey. I want it fully white. I have adobe Photoshop CS6. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Note: I need instructions, as I need to do this to many other pics.

Thanks

Comment: This is caused by the camera assuming that the image is, on average, a 15% grey, and setting the exposure and white balance accordingly.  If your camera permits it, you can avoid it in future shots by either setting a custom white balance or by deliberately overexposing the photo.

Comment: @Mark White balance has to do with hue, not brightness. So if your camera gives you the option of manual exposure, you can overexpose the image by about a stop.

Comment: @CircleB, you're right.  I thought I'd fixed a similar issue with grey snow using a custom white balance, but looking at the EXIF data, I fixed it with overexposure.

Comment: It's not a matter of "overexposing" the image but *correctly* exposing it. This image is underexposed. A correctly exposed image of a white piece of paper would have a white background and black lines. An overexposed image would have a pure white background and pale grey lines.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First you'll want to desaturate the image (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), this removes any color and makes it easier to achieve pure white.

With your file open, choose Image->Adjustments->Levels. You'll get this:
[image]

Now bring the two outer triangles in like this (you'll need to play around with this until you get something you like):

[image]

You should end up with this!

[image]

Comment: This one worked pretty nice. Sometimes a black spot remains in the corner though, but I think I can manually fix that.

Comment: +1 I always use this method every time I adjust images taken from my phone. Sometimes a little manual rubbing out is required for the odd darker spot but it usually does the trick in one

Comment: If you do this with an adjustment layer instead of 'destructively', you can even copy the layer from picture to picture, and only tweak the settings as needed.

Comment: @bakabaka, that is very true, you could also make an action and run it on an entire folder of images.

Comment: An easier way to do this with the same control panel is to use the eyedroppers pictured. Choose the white one and then select a white point. Then choose the black one and choose a black point. After that I like to adjust the output levels manually to fine tune. But the eyedroppers make this task tons easier.

Comment: @JakeGould that can be the case sometimes, but if the paper is mottled it can be hard to get the "darkest white" spot and if you have to fine tune it anyway why not just pull the slider once rather than use the eyedropper and then the slider?

Answer (score 25):

I came up with a nice method for cleaning up pictures like this, and it works even when the background or lighting is uneven (that is, far worse cases than the example in this question) and it retains the colour.

My instructions are based on the Gimp, but it would be very similar in other programs like Photoshop.

*EDIT: Gimp has a filter called "Difference of Gaussians" which implements the process described below in one step.*

Firstly, make a duplicate of the layer:

[image: layer dialog]

Blur the copied layer with a Gaussian blur. Use a kernel size large enough that you can't make out any detail from the original image. I used 100px for the picture in the original post.

[image: gaussian blur dialog]

It will look like this:

[image: blurred fish picture]

Then set the "mode" of the blurred layer to "Divide".

[image: layer dialog with mode set to divide]

The resulting image should be the line art on a white background.

[image: fish picture with background removed]

What you are doing here is essentially a high-pass-filter on the image, removing the low-frequency information (slow changes in the background colour) and keeping the high-frequency information (the line art).

Comment: Actually I just realised that in the Gimp there is a filter called "Difference of Gaussians" which does exactly this, but in one step ;)

Comment: So edit your answer!

Comment: @DavidRicherby Since the question was originally about Photoshop, a post effectively saying "neener-neener, Gimp can do it in one step" would not be very useful to the OP. I've described a method using relatively fundamental image manipulations that should be available in most graphics packages, Photoshop included.

Comment: Actually, it's perfectly fine to suggest another method in another software for other users. You may not get as many votes because it is not focused entirely towards the OPs question, but we **always** welcome alternatives.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter besides doing this in PS is exactly the steps described just different screenshots. Same applies to imagemagick etc.

Answer (score 10):

Ramp the contrast up with curves.

**Instructions:**

Select your image and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>. This will bring up the curves dialog.
[image]
Move the top point left and the bottom point right until your image becomes black and white. (that rhymes!)

Comment: I can't explain it, but sometimes this method works better. Sometimes I have to use both methods lol.

Comment: @omega this method offers more control.

Answer (score 5):

For people who don't have Adobe Photoshop, here's a free and cross-platform alternative:

Using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), it can be done in command line

`convert lQchR.png -auto-level -white-threshold 78% fish.png`

[image]

This may require some fine tuning of the white threshold value, but it's quicker than GUI especially when you have multiple pictures:

`convert *.png -auto-level -white-threshold 78% x-%04d.png`

---

Edit:

Another method using division was pointed out in the comments by joojaa

`convert fish.png ( +clone -blur 0x80 ) -compose Divide_Src -composite out_fish.png`

[image]

Comment: +1 for imagemagick.  Btw you can also do the lowpass division in imagemagick, the advantage being you dont need to prime the balance value. Which is arguably better in terms of automation.

Comment: @joojaa I'm not familiar with that option. Feel free to edit a new paragraph into the answer if it works better

Comment: @Timmy `convert fish.png ( +clone -blur 0x80 ) -compose Divide_Src -composite out_fish.png` the method is described [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#divide). Add auto level if you wish.

Comment: @joojaa Thank you. I added it to the answer along with the result

Answer (score -1):

ImageMagick convert command may have conflict with Windows convert command.  So you have to specify the full path.

Suppose we want to change the grey background of image phototext.png and create a new image phototext1.png.

Suppose ImageMagick is installed in the folder:
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16

Then write the follwing command on command prompt

"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\convert.exe" phototext.png -auto-level -white-threshold 78% phototext1.png

Comment: Hi Dr Murtaza Khan, welcome to GDSE. We follow a strict Q&A format (as opposed to a forum format), so I'm afraid your answer might get some down-votes because it doesn't really answer the question (I assume this is in response to another answer since the question makes no mention of ImageMagick). You can visit our [help] to read more about how the site works.